# How to differentiate publisher when doing FLux.zip?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am using WebClient to call few endpoints simultaneously and I need to wait all the calls to complete and from thereon, I can process these response data together.

So I am using Flux.zip. But I cannot differentiate which response data belongs to which request in subscribe().

```
Mono<ClientResponse> webclientCall1 = webClient.get().uri(urlPath1).exchange();
Mono<ClientResponse> webclientCall2 = webClient.get().uri(urlPath2).exchange();

Flux.zip(webclientCall1, webclientCall2 , webclientCall3, ...).subscribe( tuples ->
   {
     ClientResponse r1 = tuples.getT1();
     ClientResponse r2 = tuples.getT2();
     etc...

     Mono<MyPojo> bodyMono1 = r1.bodyToMono(MyPojo.class);
     Mono<MyPojo> bodyMono2 = r2.bodyToMono(MyPojo.class);
     etc..

     bodyMono1.subscribe(myPojo -> // actual body)
     etc..
   } 
)
```

I know i can do bodyToMono instead of exchange.

In either case, in subscribe, ClientReponse cannot tell, the response is coming from which request, request url information is lost...

Comment: So you want the request url for every clientResponse object, is it?

Comment: @AbhinabaChakraborty yes I need to know which clientResponse belongs to which request.

Comment: I dont understand , what is the difficulty in that? ClientResponse `r1` belongs to request url `urlPath1` and so on. If you have a list, then also, the i-th value of the tuple corresponds to the i-th request

Comment: @AbhinabaChakraborty not really, urlPath1 can be r2 also

Comment: I uses Flux.zip (iterable, combinator), the results in subscirbe is array Object[], the order is no longer the same as input "iterable"

Comment: You can do it by just a little change: `Flux.just(uri1, uri2, ...).subscribeOn(someSchedular, true).map(u -> webClient.get().uri(u).exchange())...` Return a `Tuple` when `map`ing. Play around this stuff.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat With just and map, I cannot combine all the body when all requests are done. That's why I m using zip

Comment: @AniketSahrawat ah, thank you, you're right. the ouput sustain order ~ i was confused as my log is showing different threads

Comment: Every request has his own logPrefix(), it helps you to differentiate responses

Comment: @YauhenBalykin logPrefix comes as  empty string when LOG_ID_ATTRIBUTE is not set